# resolve the instance of interface implementation

Tags: java

For e.g. If I have a interface and two implementation classes. Then I have class where I have to validate based on the implementation instance because each has its own validation. Now I m using instanceof to resolve this. Is there a better way to do this than the below code I have written?

```
    public interface TestService{
         public boolean testMethod();
    }

    public class TestServiceImpA implements TestService{
        public boolean testMethod(){
          return true;
    }
    //some other implementation
    }
    public class TestServiceImpB implements TestService{
        public boolean testMethod(){
          return false;
    }
     //some other implementation
    }

    import org.api.TestService;
    public class ClassB {

       public void methodValidator(TestService service){
    //here I have to write some validation for each type.
    //I have done this like
    if(service instanceof TestServiceImpA)
    {
       TestType testype = TestUtil.getTestType(service.getId());
     //now I need to validate testype based on this instaceof the interface
    }
    if(service instanceof TestServiceImpb)
    {
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Create a method in the interface and implement it in the implementing classes

Comment: could n't do that. because these implementation class has associated class where they dont have access to.

Comment: Could you explain your last comment?  It isn't clear to me.  Why can't you add a `validator` method or something like that to `TestService`?

Comment: I m not validating the elements of the TestService but a variable from a class associated with it.

Comment: for e.g say I getElementId() from service. Then I can pass this variable to find another element in a another class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comments aren't helping clear anything up.  Please try updating your question and adding some code (even if it isn't legal) that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.  I might be able to understand code better than English in this case.

Comment: Not sure--what do you want to do if it's `TestServiceImpB`?  If there's something in common with what you're doing for `TestServiceImpA`, then you want to think about what's common about the two interfaces and the operation you're trying to perform, and see if you can generalize it to come up with a method that can be added to the interface.  If there's nothing in common, then using this interface is probably a poor design.  But I can't yet tell.

Comment: Please post a [more complete (but still minimal) example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which clearly demonstrates the problem and how you've attempted to solve it. As it stands, the example is too vague for us to tell how you need help. The example may not need to actually compile and run, but it's clear from the discussion in the comments that you've left out important details.